# uBlock blocking "Go back to top" button (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, adblock

I have simple code of this function on website, but uBlock block the button.

The code is blocked the second time when I refresh the page, works fine the first time. To start working again you need to restart web browser.

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#go-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#go-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#go-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS code:

```
.go-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<a id="go-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg go-to-top" role="button">Go to top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason uBlock blocks elements with id and class name "go-to-top".

Just change their names to, for example, "go-up" and everything starts working.